# Where can I download the coordinates of navigation fixes/intersections?

Tags: navigation, gnss, ifr-navigation

Is there an exportable public database that I may get a copy of all navigational fixes and their corresponding GPS coordinates (latitude, longitude)? 
p.s. Only US airspace navigation fix information is needed.

Comment: It would help if you could elaborate a little. Do you want the database of all the fixes in the U.S. Airspace, or Europe, or worldwide?

Comment: NFDC [56 Day NASR Subscription](https://nfdc.faa.gov/xwiki/bin/view/NFDC/56DaySub-2015-06-25). Search for *Fix* in the sets. Only for the US.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can think of would be the [Navigraph FMS data](https://www.navigraph.com/fmsdata.aspx), however this is provided in multiple formats. Otherwise you can use [Skyvector](http://skyvector.com) to look at them graphically.